# R Limma P-Value vs Foldchange on cytokine data

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor, limma

I am trying to work with `limma` from Bioconductor to calculate the p-values and foldchange values and find differentially expressed genes.

My data looks like this.

```
 1. CYTO     Value  
ABC1       2.3   
ABC2    2.3   
ABC3    2.5   
...  
    PQR1    3.1  
 PQR2    3.2  
 PQR3    3.1
```

I want to use the `limma` package to first compute `design = model.matrix(~0+group)` and then `fit <- lmFit(Data$VALUE , design)` after which I can use the `eBayes()` function and calculate p-values and fold change values.

NOTE: We are trying to find which gene EG: ABC1, is more differentially expressed then another. 
2: gene name is a combination `gene_name` and visit info eg: ABC1 (1 is the 1st visit)

Comment: This is not a good question for Stack Overflow for a couple of reasons. (1) There is no reproducible sample data nor code example. SO deals with *specific* coding issues, and it is usually very difficult to help with questions of the form "How do I do XYZ" if you don't provide sample data for us to work with. (2) The `limma` documentation is *very* comprehensive and well written. Based on your sample data, you should be able to start implementing a differential gene expression analysis following the instructions from the documentation. You can also find many tutorials on the web. [...]

Comment: [continued] (3) I don't understand your sample data. Differential gene expression usually requires a *count table* (if you're analysing RNA-seq data) that gives the number of reads (counts) per gene per sample. The design matrix then species which samples belong to which condition, which determines the model that is used to fit your data. The sample data you provide doesn't look like a count table. (4) Overall, this question might be a better fit for SEQanswers or Biostars; but also on those sites you need to provide more details.